# Ejabberd Oauth: Access denied

Tags: oauth, xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-api, ejabberd-auth

I installed and configured an Ejabberd XMPP server. I tested connecting to the server from a mobile app and exchanging messages. Now I want to enable OAuth(need to integrate OAuth token generation into my own Node.js REST API: login on my REST API = login on my DB + Ejabberd OAuth token generation). I want to prevent doing 2 login calls (my REST API + Ejabberd) by generating the token within my REST API login and  use this token in my Android/Ios apps.

When I open this url:

> http://my-server:5280/oauth/authorization_token?response_type=token&client_id=Client1&redirect_uri=http://my-server:3000/ejabberd&scope=get_roster+sasl_auth

I get a login form, after filling the form with valid credentials I get redirected to this url:

> http://my-server:5280/oauth/authorization_token

with an empty response: **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**

```
For reference, here is my configuration file:

hosts:
  - "test"
  - "157.245.128.100"

loglevel: 5
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rotate_count: 1
log_rate_limit: 100

certfiles:
  - "/opt/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"
  #- "/opt/ejabberd/proxym.dev.pem"
##  - "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem"
##  - "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/privkey.pem"

ca_file: "/opt/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: false
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: false
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/api": mod_http_api
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/captcha": ejabberd_captcha
      "/upload": mod_http_upload
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      #"/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
      "/api": mod_http_api
  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

s2s_use_starttls: optional
#disable_sasl_mechanisms: ["X-OAUTH2"]
acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
      - ::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@test"

access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          acl: loopback
          acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            acl: loopback
            acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number
  commands_admin_access:
    who: all
  commands:
    what:
      - "user"
      - "admin"
      - "open"

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

max_fsm_queue: 10000

acme:
   contact: "mailto:admin@test"
   ca_url: "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org"

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
    docroot: /home/upload
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    ## db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: never
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      allow_subscription: true  # enable MucSub
      mam: false
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false
#  mod_admin_extra: {}
#commands_admin_access: configure
#commands:
#  - add_commands:
#    - user
#oauth_expire: 3600
#oauth_access: all

commands_admin_access:
  - allow:
    - user: "admin@test"
commands:
  - add_commands: [user, admin, open]
oauth_expire: 31536000
oauth_access: all

### Local Variables:
### mode: yaml
### End:
### vim: set filetype=yaml tabstop=8
### host_config:
sql_type: mysql
sql_server: "157.245.128.100"
sql_database: "ejabberd"
sql_username: "ejabberd"
sql_password: "password"
sql_port: 3306
auth_method: sql
default_db: sql
```

Comment: for user(jid) in the login form are you putting jid ie alongwith the hostname. admin@hostname. Since with your configuration, I tried and I am getting oauth token.

Comment: Can you please send the configuration file you tried and the URL you have used

Comment: https://localhost:5443/oauth/authorization_token?response_type=token&client_id=Client1&scope=ejabberd:admin I reverted the configuration as you have since I was working. The above link is for my configuration on 5443 port.

Comment: @IrrupTor I found this in the logs:
 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.723.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: call to undefined function ejabberd_oauth:verify_resowner_scope({user,<<"admin">>,<<"test">>}, [<<"get_roster">>,<<"sasl_auth">>], {password,<<"password">>})
[error] Supervisor ejabberd_http_sup had child undefined started with {ejabberd_http,start_link,undefined} at <0.723.0> exit with reason call to undefined function ejabberd_oauth:verify_resowner_scope({user,<<"admin">>,<<"test">>}, [<<"get_roster">>,<<"sasl_auth">>], {password,<<"password">>}) in context child_terminated

Comment: what version of ejabberd are you using? You will have problem in calling rest api also when you use ejabberd 19.06, hence I am using ejabberd 19.02, which is working fine.

Comment: I am using version 19.08

Comment: please try using 19.02.

Comment: @IrrupTor I installed version 19.02 and it looks fine. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out that you have following configuration added in your configuration yml.

```
commands_admin_access:
  - allow:
    - user: "admin@localhost"  # your user name.
commands:
  - add_commands: [user, admin, open]

oauth_access:
  - allow:
    - user:
      - "admin@localhost"  # add your user name

oauth_expire: 86400
```

Please follow the link here:
https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/simple-configuration/

You might have missed some configuration from up, since I also ran into similar problem but found that I was missing some part of above configuration.

Comment: Still getting the same issue, I am sure that I am not configuring ejabberd right.
I will update my question to include the configuration file